# Set Text for EA Element Linked Document

Tags: enterprise-architect

When EA element is Created we can set the linked document for the element.The API used for this is mobjElement.LoadLinkedDocument(string fileName) . Instead Of setting the file name can't we insert the string directly to the document. In the EA tables where we can find the linked document contents.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: No. You need to use a temporary file and pass this to `LoadLinkedDocument`.

The content of the linked documents is stored in `t_document.BinContent WHERE ElementType="SSDOCSTYLE"`. It's a base64 encoded zip with a single file `str.dat`.

Comment: No the contents of files are not present in t_document.BinContent